# How and where to link related DATA records in VUE, using sequelize, express, finale and axios

Tags: rest, vue.js, orm, sequelize.js

My VUE app architecture is following:

```
- REST service (express, Sequelize, finale)
- API to talk with REST
- end app in VUE
```

My service provides and handles following data models:

```
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});
```

and I have following end points shared from my REST:

```
let projectsSRV = finale.resource({
  model: Project,
  endpoints: ['/projects', '/projects/:id']
})
let usersSRV = finale.resource({
  model: USER,
  ndpoints: ['/users', '/users/:id']
})
```

It's many-to-many relation, as a result I have additional table UserProject, that links both original records.
My question is following. Assuming that end user needs to link selected Project with selected User, then:
Where and how shall I create UserProject link record? in my API? on my REST? other? HOW can I do this? By manually creating link object? it looks like I do't have an access to UserProject type in my vue file. Unfortunatelly I'm new in VUE :-)
Thanks